# changing id within javascript with onClick var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I managed to get some js to work to my surprise, now I want to make it a little more complex which is way out of my expertise.

I have a button when clicked will reload a iframe that is on my page. I have multiple iframes all but 1 are hidden. Then I use jquery to display a different iframe and hidden the previous depending on the nav button clicked. e.g. "1-btn" (nav btn) tied to "1-win" (iframe), "2-btn" (nav btn) tied to "2-win" (iframe) etc. So when you click "2-btn", "1-win" iframe hides and "2-win" iframe is displayed. Now I want to change my code so this ties into my reload javasrcipt. Currently, my js only reloads 1 iframe via the iframe id. I want to change this id every time to a different iframe. This will allow my Reload btn to only reload the current iframe displayed and not any of the other that are hidden.

Here is my Reload js

```
function Reload () {
var f = document.getElementById('1-win');
f.src = f.src;
}
```

As you can see this reload script only works for iframe "1-win". When i click "2-btn" nav to display "2-win" iframe (and hides "1-win") the reload button still only works for "1-win". Therefore, I want it to also change. For e.g. when I click "2-btn" (nav) to display "2-win" iframe I want to change the Reload id to "2-win" also.

I was thinking of using onClick within my nav buttons which passed through the id of the iframe which that nav btn is tied to. However, I have no idea how to do this.

For full code see:
https://github.com/tmacka88/Service-Manager

Sorry if this doesn't make any sense, I cant think of an easier way to explain it.

Thanks

Comment: can you give your site url ??

Comment: https://github.com/tmacka88/Service-Manager

working on index.html

Comment: I have edited to try to simplify as best I can

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
This below answer may or may not still apply now that the problem has been better defined.

---

One approach you could try is having a hidden field on the page which contains a semi-colon separated list of the Id's of the iframes. E.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="iframeids" value="1;2;3;4;5">
```

On the click event of your button, call some JavaScript which gets the `value` of the hidden field, takes the first token before the semicolon, and then reorganise the string. An example:

```
// Next value is 1
// Use 1 in your JS
// Put 1 to the end, next is now 2
<input type="hidden" name="iframeids" value="2;3;4;5;1">
```

You would contain the logic of re-arranging etc. in the JS function.

Comment: Well, break it into chunks, if you need help with a particular chunk, I'm, happy to help...

Comment: sorry, I thought it was the same thing. I don't no any js so am a little confused how to do it all. What I was referring to in my edit was, can I change the Reload ID with a onClick in the nav button which is associated an iframe. I am really trying to explain things as easily as I can but i cant think of any other way of explaining it.

Comment: Ok, I'm happy to help you come up with a detailed solution but I will keep editing it with further detail as required, to avoid going into too much detail initially.  Please upvote the answer if you are finding it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Now that the problem is better defined, we can work out a proper solution.

Here are some design considerations:

1. Ideally you do not want to manually add a new button for every iframe that you put on the page. Main reason being **code maintenance**. If you were to add a new iframe, or remove one, your code would not function correctly.  Also the amount of mark-up required will be unnecessarily high
2. jQuery will make your life easier, although it's not required, it will cut out a lot of code. I can't stress enough the importance of knowing JavaScript basics first, but this is your responsibility to learn
   For point 1, what we would like is a generic solution so that if you add more iframes, the buttons are added automatically. JavaScript is the way to do this (I'm assuming this is just HTML, not ASP.net or php or some other server side

Point 2 - jQuery will help with point 1.

Now we have this understanding, let's look at an outline of what we need to do:

1. In JavaScript, loop through the `iframe` tags on the page
2. For each `iframe`, generate a button using jquery, using the values like `src` and `id` in the `iframe` as attributes on the button
3. Add some `click`-event code to the button do define what it needs to do when clicked
4. Again using jQuery, add the newly created buttons to the DOM

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help and advice. I figured it out. Yes i need to tidy up my code so it works better, but I don't think I can use only 1 iframe because if I do it will reload that iframe each time and not remember what is was doing, also it continues it's task in the background while using another iframe. cheers

Comment: I didn't suggest only using 1 iframe :-) It was a case of dynamically creating the buttons which link to the iframes you have defined.  Anyway, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
function Reload()
{
    $("iframe").each(function() 
    {
        if($(this).is(':visible'))
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    });
}
```